# Is there a way to trigger a script on sftp session exit?

Tags: linux, ssh, sftp, .bash-logout

I'm looking for a way to start a shell script after a sftp session exited.

Is it possible to trigger `/home/user/.bash_logout` via sftp, how does it work?

I tried to set `RequestTTY force` in `~/.ssh/config` but this is not helping.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible on remote server to start any command after sftp session is over, it is because all what is executed on remote server while having sftp is content of `SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND` env variable which points to `*sftp-server` binary.

If you want to do anything on remote server, just create a wrapper and "force" it either via `ForceCommand` or via `command=` in your ssh public key in `.ssh/authorized_keys`.

For example I was playing with such wrapper to automatically `rsync` mirror users data after sftp session is over to another server.